# A Python class for handling mortality (and lapse) probabilities

Tags: python, object-oriented

I'm developing a model in Python which produces IFRS and SII balance sheets for a hypothetical life insurance company. To value the hypothetical company's insurance liabilities, I need to project the probability of a policy being redeemed in a given year.

Policies may be redeemed in two possible ways:

1. The policy holder dies
2. The policy lapses (the policy-holder voluntarily chooses to redeem it)

The function relied upon most heavily in this module is `prob_death()` which gives the probability that a policy holder dies in a given year. Since they must die eventually, the sum of these probabilities will be 1.0.

The csv file 'mortality_data.csv' contains probabilities that a person who is currently alive and aged x will survive to age x+1.

This is the code:

```
# Import external libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class Mortality:

    def __init__(self, lapse_rate=0.0, mortality_stress=None):

        if type(lapse_rate) == list:
            self.lapse_rate = np.array(lapse_rate)
        else:
            self.lapse_rate = lapse_rate

        self.mortality_stress = mortality_stress

        # Read in mortality data and set age as index
        self.mort_data = pd.read_csv('inputs/mortality_data.csv', index_col='Age')

        # Apply mortality stress if applicable
        self.mort_data = apply_stress(self.mort_data, mortality_stress)

    def q(self, x):
        return self.mort_data.loc[x, 'Death Prob']

    def prob_in_force(self):

        qx_curve = model.mort_data['Death Prob'].to_list()
        df_qx = pd.DataFrame([[0] + qx_curve[i:] + [0] * i for i in range(0, len(qx_curve))],
                             index=[x for x in range(17, 121)])

        if type(self.lapse_rate) == np.ndarray:
            lapse_rate = np.insert(self.lapse_rate, 0, 0.0)[:-1]
        else:
            lapse_rate = self.lapse_rate

        decr_probs = (df_qx + lapse_rate - df_qx * lapse_rate).clip(0, 1)
        cond_if_probs = (1 - decr_probs)
        if_probs = cond_if_probs.cumprod(axis=1)

        return if_probs

    def prob_death(self):

        # Get the probabilities of lives of each possible age being inforce at each point in time
        df_prob_in_force = self.prob_in_force()

        # Get the qx values for all possible ages of interest
        qx_curve = (self.q([x for x in range(17, 121)])).to_list()

        # Construct a DataFrame whose (i, j)th entry is q(i+j)
        # TODO: Refactor
        df_qx = pd.DataFrame([qx_curve[i:] + [0] * (i+1) for i in range(0, len(qx_curve))], index=[x for x in range(17, 121)])
        decr_probs = (df_qx + self.lapse_rate - df_qx * self.lapse_rate).clip(0, 1)

        # Multiply the probability inforce at each time by the probability of dying during that year
        df_prob_death = decr_probs * df_prob_in_force

        # Increment columns by 1 and return the result
        df_prob_death.columns += 1
        return df_prob_death

    def simulate_mortality(self, policy_data):

        # Simulate a random number between 0 and 1 for each in-force policy
        np_test_stats = np.random.uniform(size=policy_data.shape[0])

        # Get the qx value for each policy
        qx = self.q(policy_data['Age'])

        # Flag each policy as still in-force if and only if the simulated random value is greater than the qx
        # probability for that policy
        np_pol_if_flags = (np_test_stats > qx).to_numpy()

        # Return only the policies from the inputted policy data whose in-force flag is true
        return policy_data[np_pol_if_flags]


def apply_stress(base_mortality_curve, stress):

    if type(stress) == str:
        # Read in the multiplicative stress factors for each stress
        mort_stress_factors = pd.read_csv('inputs/mortality_stress_factors.csv', index_col='Stress')

        # Multiply the original qx probabilities by the multiplicative stress factor for the chosen stress
        base_mortality_curve['Death Prob'] *= mort_stress_factors.loc[stress, 'Factor']

    if type(stress) == float:
        base_mortality_curve['Death Prob'] *= 1 + stress

    # Subject all qx probabilities to a cap of 1 and a floor of 0 and return the result
    return base_mortality_curve.clip(0, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = Mortality([0.08] * 5 + [0.01] * 100)
    foo = model.prob_death()
    print(foo)
```

To run this code without need for the .csv file, simply replace the line

```
self.mort_data = pd.read_csv('inputs/mortality_data.csv', index_col='Age')
```

with

```
self.mort_data = pd.DataFrame([0.0006, 0.000594, 0.000587, 0.000582, 0.000577, 0.000572, 0.000569, 0.000567, 0.000566, 0.000567, 0.00057, 0.000574, 0.00058, 0.00059, 0.000602, 0.000617, 0.000636, 0.00066, 0.000689, 0.000724, 0.000765, 0.000813, 0.00087, 0.000937, 0.001014, 0.001104, 0.001208, 0.001327, 0.001465, 0.001622, 0.001802, 0.002008, 0.002241, 0.002508, 0.002809, 0.003152, 0.003539, 0.003976, 0.004469, 0.005025, 0.00565, 0.006352, 0.00714, 0.008022, 0.009009, 0.010112, 0.011344, 0.012716, 0.014243, 0.01594, 0.017824, 0.019913, 0.022226, 0.024783, 0.027606, 0.030718, 0.034144, 0.037911, 0.042046, 0.046578, 0.051538, 0.056956, 0.062867, 0.069303, 0.0763, 0.083893, 0.092117, 0.101007, 0.1106, 0.120929, 0.132028, 0.143929, 0.15666, 0.170247, 0.184714, 0.200079, 0.216354, 0.233548, 0.251662, 0.270688, 0.290613, 0.311414, 0.333058, 0.355505, 0.378702, 0.402588, 0.42709, 0.452127, 0.477608, 0.503432, 0.529493, 0.555674, 0.581857, 0.607918, 0.633731, 0.659171, 0.684114, 0.708442, 0.732042, 0.754809, 0.776648, 0.797477, 0.817225, 1.0], index=range(17, 121), columns=['Death Prob'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function names are not always very intuitive unless perhaps one works in the same field as you. But since they are small it could make sense to gather the comments into one single docstring declaration at the top, so that the purpose is explained in one simple paragraph.

There seems to be a problem of structure. At first glance, the indentation suggests that the function `apply_stress` does not belong here. But since you are calling that function within your class (in your `__init__` method) it really is part of it and needs to be embedded as well. It could qualify as static method.

The **init** does too many things. It should just "set up" the class but not run anything that is not strictly necessary for its instantiation. It should be possible to pass some arguments, such as the data source before the class goes on to perform the heavy work. Hardcoding file names is not a good idea. In its current form, the class cannot be reused easily without making changes to its code.

The handling of variables is problematic. Expecting a variable in different possible types (str, float) suggests that there is a lack of control (or quality control) on the data. This is quite dangerous and will likely cause runtime bugs if the variable type is allowed to change along the process.

The reasons are obvious. Depending on variable type, the applicable functions and methods will be different. Normalize the data so that it is delivered to your functions in a predictable and consistent format.

Type hinting would help here. Explicitly declaring the expected type will serve as a visual guide, and keep you focused on providing what the function expects from you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Two questions though:

I defined `apply_stresses` outside of the class because I didn't want it to be accessible as a class method. If I define it as a static method within the class, can I still make it inaccessible outside of the class?

Is it the call to `apply_stresses` in the `__init__` function that you're referring to when you say that nothing should be run from `__init__`? This could be moved to the `q(x)` method (I can see why you might think this is poorly named, but q_x is standard actuarial notation.

Comment: I would normally create a separate, *stand-alone* .py file per class, that you can import whenever needed. That class should embed the functions it depends on, so it can run on its own, or you are looking to create something else like a module. You could define so-called private methods using [mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) though. Note that your class exposes more stuff like `mort_data`, that should remain private to the class. Likewise, some methods are probably not supposed to be visible and made directly available to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if type(lapse_rate) == list:
            self.lapse_rate = np.array(lapse_rate)
        else:
            self.lapse_rate = lapse_rate
```

This seems a tediously long way to save a tiny bit
of effort in the case where caller passed in an ndarray.

Just unconditionally assign `np.array(lapse_rate)`
and be done with it.
Now it is clear to the Gentle Reader and
to `mypy` or other inference engine
that we *definitely* are storing an ndarray at that point.
Constructing a copy of the correct type,
with `list(already_a_list)` or `np.array(already_an_array)`,
has O(N) complexity in both space and time and
is otherwise harmless.
Plus, then the caller needn't worry about
whether that argument was possibly mutated.

Or make it clear that caller must pass in exactly *this*
kind of datastructure, and no other.
Raise [fatal error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
if caller messed up.

---

```
    def q(self, x):
```

Give us a hint in the """docstring""" that
this is **quantile**, please.
Or cite a reference using the standard notation which mentions that.

---

```
def apply_stress(base_mortality_curve, stress):
```

In addition to "no stress"
there are two kinds of stresses that can be applied: global
"multiplicative", and a variant that I'm not yet sure how to name.
Testing `type(stress)` works, but it's not terrific.
Consider breaking this into a pair of Optional parameters,
`stress_multiplicative` and the other one.
That will make several things easier,
including writing and comprehending the documentation.

---

The mention in `prob_in_force()`
of `range(0, len(qx_curve))`
could safely omit `0`, as it is default.
Whatever.

And the typical way to write `[x for x in ...]`
is: `index=list(range(17, 121))`

Those [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
definitely need names, maybe `MIN_AGE` and `MAX_AGE`.
Perhaps they could be derived from the CSV or the DataFrame?

```
        if type(self.lapse_rate) == np.ndarray:
            lapse_rate = np.insert(self.lapse_rate, 0, 0.0)[:-1]
        else:
            lapse_rate = self.lapse_rate
```

I don't understand what's going on there.
Surely the `__init__` ctor established a
[class invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant)
that the attribute's type shall be ndarray, no?
Why the tedious conditional?
Is it possible to write a unit test which
[covers](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov)
that 2nd clause?

There's nothing especially wrong with
creating a local temporary variable
similarly named to the object attribute.
But you might choose to abbreviate it
or otherwise give it a slightly different name.
My concern is that *you* know what's happening,
but a year from now a maintenance engineer
might alter `lapse_rate` and then wonder why
another method isn't seeing that alteration.
BTW, the
[documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)
observes:

> Note that insert does not occur in-place: a new array is returned.

`(df_qx + lapse_rate - df_qx * lapse_rate)`
seems like a non-intuitive way of expressing

`(df_qx * (1 - lapse_rate))`.

I *think* that `if_probs` is shorthand for
[international finance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Financial_Reporting_Standards)
probabilities?
That is, I *think* it is trying to conform
to some regulatory framework.
It really needs a citation to some reference.

---

In `prob_death()` please delete this comment:

```
        # Increment columns by 1 and return the result
```

Or make it informative, perhaps by elaborating
on the meaning of the `columns` data structure.

It's unclear to me what sort of refactoring the TODO is asking for,
maybe Extract Helper?
Certainly we could
[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
up some copy-pasted expressions that use `{MIN,MAX}_AGE`,
since `prob_{death,in_force}()` compute similar things.

---

```
    foo = model.prob_death()
```

No.
Give it a real name, please.

Or go with an anonymous `print(model.prob_death())`.

---

No unit tests appeared in this submission.
That will complicate any attempts at refactoring.

This code appears to achieve its design objectives.

I would not be willing to accept maintenance tasks
on this codebase in its current form, it is not sufficiently clear.
I would be willing to delegate maintenance tasks
to an engineer who is also an actuarial Subject Matter Expert.

Comment: Thanks for all the constructive feedback. The reason for the `type(lapse_rate)` conditional is that it could be either a list (of floats) or a float. The latter would be used if the same lapse rate were to be applied at all terms. I could force the user to always pass an np.array (even when applying a flat lapse rate which could be specified as a single float), but this would make the function more effort to call.

Comment: The TODO (which I didn't mean to leave in for this question) is there because I was trying to find a way to vectorise this line. That is, if pandas has native functionality for constructing a dataframe by permuting a series n times.

Comment: Wow, very interesting about Author's Intent for the `lapse_rate` parameter, I had not guessed that. We review code to see (1) if it is correct, meaning that others find it a "convincing argument", and (2) if it is maintainable, meaning that others would implement features and fixes in line with the original design. Sooo, the lack of documentation around that parameter, container vs scalar, is one of the more important results to highlight from this review. Adopting optional type annotations, and linting with `mypy`, would be good action items to take away from this.